# validation.yml file is ignored

Tags: php, validation, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm new to symfony, and I'm currently trying to understand Symfony3.
While validation through annotations works fine, I can't activate validation through validation.yml file.

In my app/config/config.yml, I changed this line :

```
framework:
    validation:      { enabled: true, enable_annotations: false }
```

My src/AppBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml is :

```
# src/AppBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml
AppBundle\Entity\TaskSetClass:
    properties:
        taskName:
            - NotBlank: ~
        dueDate:
            - NotBlank: ~
            - Type: \DateTime
```

I added a extension file :

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/DependencyInjection/AppExtension.php
namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;
/* */
class AppExtension extends Extension
    {
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
        {
        $container=new ContainerBuilder();
        // Services
        $loader=new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../../../app/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
        // Validation
        // Commented : No "validator.mapping.loader.yaml_files_loader.mapping_files" parameter.
        //$yamlMappingFiles=$container->getParameter('validator.mapping.loader.yaml_files_loader.mapping_files');
        $finder=new Finder();
        foreach($finder->files()->in(__DIR__.'/../../../app/Resources/config') as $file)
            {
            $filePath=$file->getRealPath();
            if(preg_match('@\.yml$@',$filePath)===1)
                {
                $yamlMappingFiles[]=$filePath;
                }
            }
        $container->setParameter('validator.mapping.loader.yaml_files_loader.mapping_files', $yamlMappingFiles);
        }
    }
```

A dump of the container after the setParameter() in appExtension.php shows the command has succeeded :

```
[parameterBag:protected] => Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBag Object
    (
    [parameters:protected] => Array
        (
        [validator.mapping.loader.yaml_files_loader.mapping_files] => Array
            (
            [0] => /mnt/400Go/www/sy1/app/Resources/config/validation.yml
            )
        )
    [resolved:protected] => 
    )
```

In my form controller, if I list the constraints :

```
[...]
if($form->isSubmitted())
    {
    if($form->isValid())
        {
        $metadata=$this->container
                 ->get('validator')
                 ->getMetadataFor('AppBundle\Entity\TaskSetClass');
        $propertiesMetadata=$metadata->properties;
        $constraints=array();
        foreach ($propertiesMetadata as $propertyMetadata)
            {
            $constraints[$propertyMetadata->name]=$property->constraints;
            }
        echo'<pre>Constraints : ';
        print_r($constraints);
        echo'</pre>';
        die();
        [...]
```

... the array is empty. so the file seems to be loaded, but the constraints are ignored.

Did anyone encountered this error? It may comes from a difference between symfony 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED] The validation file was not in the correct directory. It was supposed to be in AppBundle/Resources/config and I had it into app/Resouces/config. Works fine now.

Comment: That's sad, since this is currently the only configuration file that needs to be placed inside a bundle. Pretty much inconsistent